# Apply css class to leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

Is it possible to add/apply css class to leaflet layer ? I have 3 layers and I want to style image background differently according to each layer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path), adding classes can be done for vector overlays (Polygon, Polyline, Circle) using the `className` option. This doesn't seem to be available for [tile layers](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-options) though.

But I found a solution/workaround by adding a class directly to the underlying HTML element:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

var osmLayer = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
osmLayer.getContainer().classList.add('osmLayer');
```

Comment: It appears that tileLayer, being extended from gridLayer, now supports the className option.